# Modifying the built-in behavior of ajax tag type-ahead functionality of WordPress

Tags: admin, tags, dashboard

Currently, it takes 3 characters to be entered into the tags, before WordPress can start suggesting matching tags.

Where do I make it so it instantly starts those suggestions?

I've got a 100's of tags that start with dash character (-) and I'd like to get to them real fast.

in my custom taxonomy, "source", I tag the organization names starting with dash. Example, -cnn, -bbc, -kabc, -new your times etc. and I tag the author names normally such as Larry King. To get to the orgs being suggested fast, I thought I need to modify the at-least-3-letter-needed behavior. This way, I can just type -c and boom -cnn would be showing.

Feel free to comment to this approach please.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult. The value is hard coded in `wp-admin/js/post.js`. See `wp-admin/js/post.dev.js` `tagBox.init()` for more readable code:

```
$(this).suggest( ajaxurl + '?action=ajax-tag-search&tax=' + tax, 
{ 
    delay: 500, minchars: 2, multiple: true, multipleSep: postL10n.comma + ' ' 
} );
```

The only solution I can see: Unregister the script with the handle `'post'` (see `wp-includes/script-loader.php`) and register a custom copy where you change the `minchars` value.

Comment: not yet, toscho. we are stumbled upon some other issues. eventually, we will get back on track to take care of those matters.